# select random number of points along an axis in tensorflow

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a 3-dimensional array of the mask of size (X, Y, N) with each value 1 or 0. We want to collect indices in the last dimension when the value is 1.

```
X, Y, N = 10, 10, 10
# Each point in ar is 1 or 0
ar = tf.random.uniform((X, Y, N), maxval=2, seed=1, name=None, dtype=tf.int32)
# We now want to collect 4 point indices along last dimension if the corresponding value is 1
```

I want to sample n(=4) indices along 3rd dimension when the corresponding value is 1. How can I do that in tensorflow? The output of my function should be of shape (X, Y, 4)

```
if output[x, y] = [n1, n2, n3, n4] then
ar[x,y, n1] = 1
ar[x,y, n2] = 1
ar[x,y, n3] = 1
ar[x,y, n4] = 1
...
...
...
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What's mean with `when the corresponding value is 1`? What's your `output[x,y]`?

Comment: is it clearer now? I want a sampling function

Comment: What if the number of the 3rd dimension equal to 1 is less than 4?

Comment: sample with repitation @giser_yugang

Answer (score 0):

I found out you might be looking for [`tf.multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/multinomial). You just keep the probability equal when the value is `1` and the probability is `tf.log(0.0)` when the value is `0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

samples = tf.multinomial(tf.log([[1., 1., 0.0]]), 4)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(samples))

#print
[[0 1 1 1]]
```

And you also need to use `tf.map_fn` to wrap `tf.multinomial` since the log-probabilities of `tf.multinomial` requires 2-D Tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

X, Y, N = 10, 10, 10
ar = tf.random.uniform((X, Y, N), maxval=2, seed=1, name=None, dtype=tf.int32)

samples = tf.map_fn(lambda x:tf.multinomial(tf.log(x), 4,output_dtype=tf.int32)
                    ,tf.cast(ar,tf.float32)
                    ,dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    val1,val2 = sess.run([ar,samples])
    print('ar[0]: \n',val1[0])
    print('samples[0]: \n',val2[0])

ar[0]: 
 [[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]]
samples[0]: 
 [[0 1 0 4]
 [6 7 5 2]
 [4 4 4 7]
 [1 8 7 4]
 [8 7 7 3]
 [7 7 6 0]
 [7 4 3 9]
 [1 5 0 3]
 [4 1 1 7]
 [7 7 1 6]]
```

*Note that `tf.multinomial` will be removed in new version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.random.categorical instead.*